# Duplicated loading movie data when use AVPlayer, and How to stop loading movie data

Tags: ios, avplayer

I'm using AVQueuePlayer(AVPlayer) for video streams ( http protocol, MP4 format).
And my code is (referenced AV Foundation Programming Guide)

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:movieUrl];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"playable"];
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^() {
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
            AVKeyValueStatus status = [asset statusOfValueForKey:@"playable" error:&error];
            switch (status) {
                case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded: {
                    self.movieItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
                    [self.player insertItem:self.movieItem afterItem:nil];
                }
                case AVKeyValueStatusFailed: {
                    break;
                }
                case AVKeyValueStatusCancelled: {
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }];
```

And observing AVPlayer.status for play like this

```
switch (status) {
    case AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown:
        break;
    case AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay:
        NSLog(@"READY TO PLAY");
            [myPlayer play];
        break;
    case AVPlayerItemStatusFailed:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

These code is working well.
But when I'm monitoring usage of network traffic and request by monitoring tool(like fiddler) ,
I found out some problems that duplicated requesting movie url and loading data.

And I try to stop loading movie data(set player to nil OR player removeAllItems) But It's not working.

I wonder I used right way to load movie data and What should I do to stop loading.